# Filter for all terms in a "dynamic vocabulary"

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I would like to add a filter in a view to search only nodes related to terms in a specific vocabulary. The problem is that the editors continuously add terms to the vocabulary and consequently I cannot select once and for ever which are the possible terms.

I would need a filter like this:
positive if the term searched, or its translation, is in the vocabulary "myVocabulary".

Answer (score 0):

I believe contextual filters under the advanced options in your view is what you are looking for. You can add the term reference field there and then dynamically filter the view from the url with either the term name or term id or both depending on the options you select.

Comment: I have not the term, id or name, in the url. 
I need that to make a search page with exposed filters.

Comment: If you expose the filter and not select any terms by default it will display them all. 
Views Admin: http://cl.ly/image/1g0I1r0r0e0w
Output: http://cl.ly/image/1V3t1t3i1o2v